# Retaining form values when clicking cancel

Tags: javascript, forms

I have multiple html forms on a page with pre-filled value. For each form, the user has the option to modify the form and submit. But there is also a cancel button. If the user clicks the cancel button (after some modification), the original value will be retained in the form. What is the best way to do it using javascript?

I could retrieve the original value from the server. But really want to do it on the client side.

Comment: How do you prepopulate the values in the form. There are many ways to do this, but share you code, for us to understand it better.

Comment: Quentin gives the answer. it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> type: reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.

So:

```
<button type="reset">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I was struggling this for the whole day trying to do it using javascript